# Gensim ensemblelda multiprocessing: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, nlp, multiprocessing, gensim

I'm using the [gensim library](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) for topic modelling, more precisely the [Ensemble LDA](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ensemblelda.html) method. My code is fairly standard (I follow the documentation), the main part is:

```
           model = models.EnsembleLda(corpus=corpus,
                                   id2word=id2word,
                                   num_topics=ntopics,
                                   passes=2,
                                   iterations = 200,
                                   num_models=ncores,
                                   topic_model_class=models.LdaModel,
                                   ensemble_workers=nworkers,
                                   distance_workers=ncores)
```

(full code at https://github.com/erwanm/gensim-temporary/blob/main/gensim-topics.py)

But with my data I *sometimes* obtain the error below. But it also often runs correctly with a subset of the data, so I don't know if the problem is related to my data?

```
Process Process-52:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/moreaue/anaconda3/envs/twarc2/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/moreaue/anaconda3/envs/twarc2/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/moreaue/anaconda3/envs/twarc2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gensim/models/ensemblelda.py", line 534, in _asymmetric_distance_matrix_worker
    distance_chunk = _calculate_asymmetric_distance_matrix_chunk(
  File "/home/moreaue/anaconda3/envs/twarc2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gensim/models/ensemblelda.py", line 491, in _calculate_asymmetric_distance_matrix_chunk
    mask = masking_method(ttd1, masking_threshold)
  File "/home/moreaue/anaconda3/envs/twarc2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gensim/models/ensemblelda.py", line 265, in mass_masking
    smallest_valid = sorted_a[largest_mass][-1]
IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

The error seems related to multiprocessing, since `ensemblelda` runs a number of threads (each running one instance of LDA).

What can cause this error? Any advice on how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the source code, the `mass_masking` function is simply returning a boolean array (binary mask) with truth values assigned to its positions that positionally correspond to the elements of `a`: where those elements of `a`, if you had to cumulatively summate them, would remain below the `threshold` set (default is 0.95).

The line `sorted_a[largest_mask][-1]` is causing problems because nowhere in the `mass_masking` function are there any checks to make sure that the largest element of `a` is below the threshold, nor its predecessor `ttd1`. Whenever `ttd1`'s, and therefore `a`'s, largest value is equal to or above the threshold, the `IndexError` is raised because `sorted_a[largest_mass]` returns an empty array which is then attempted to be indexed by the `[-1]`. The minimal examples below showcase this issue.

`ttd1` is created in the [_calculate_asymmetric_distance_matrix_chunk()](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/ensemblelda.py#L451) function when it enumerates over `ttda1`. It calls `masking_method(ttd1, masking_threshold)`, which subsequently invokes `mass_masking` which is set as the default method upon initialisation of the `EnsembleLda` class. I suspect this is a bug that is prevalent during multiprocessing because the [_calculate_assymetric_distance_matrix_multiproc()](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/ensemblelda.py#L545) function instantiates the `Process` with the `target` set as the [_asymmetric_distance_matrix_worker()](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/ensemblelda.py#L521) function, and this `worker` function slices the `entire_ttda` to create `ttda1` which it passes to the `chunk` function, but again, there's no check to ensure it hasn't created a slice that has one of its elements equal to or larger than `threshold`.

Here is a minimal working example of how `mass_making` should function:

```py
import numpy as np


def mass_masking(a, threshold=None):
    """Original masking method. Returns a new binary mask."""
    if threshold is None:
        threshold = 0.95

    sorted_a = np.sort(a)[::-1]  # [0.5   0.449 0.2   0.1  ]
    # sorted_a.cumsum() outputs [0.5   0.949 1.149 1.249] then threshold is taken
    largest_mass = sorted_a.cumsum() < threshold  # [ True  True False False]
    # sorted_a[largest_mass] outputs [0.5   0.449] then last element is taken
    smallest_valid = sorted_a[largest_mass][-1]  # 0.449
    return a >= smallest_valid # [ True False False  True]


test_arr = np.array([0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.449])
print(mass_masking(test_arr))
# Output: [ True False False  True]
```

When `a`'s largest element is greater than or equal to 0.95, an `IndexError` is raised:

```py
import numpy as np


def mass_masking(a, threshold=None):
    """Original masking method. Returns a new binary mask."""
    if threshold is None:
        threshold = 0.95

    sorted_a = np.sort(a)[::-1]  # [0.96  0.5   0.449 0.2  ]
    # sorted_a.cumsum() outputs [0.96  1.46  1.909 2.109] then threshold is taken
    largest_mass = sorted_a.cumsum() < threshold  # [False False False False]
    # sorted_a[largest_mass] outputs [] then last element is taken
    smallest_valid = sorted_a[largest_mass][-1]  # IndexError
    return a >= smallest_valid # function fails to return binary mask


test_arr = np.array([0.5, 0.2, 0.96, 0.449])
print(mass_masking(test_arr))
# Output: IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Knowing this, and assuming I haven't misinterpreted how the whole group of `calculate_asymmetric_distance_matrix` functions are working during multiprocessing, you can either try to ensure yourself that no values are greater than or equal to the default threshold, or set the `masking_threshold` higher when initialising the EnsembleLda.